# What is the boot folder

Tags: 12.04, boot

What is the "/boot" folder in my Ubuntu 12.04 installation?

Specifically, should I include it in my backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man hier`:

> ```
> /boot  Contains static files for the boot loader.  This directory holds
>        only the files which are needed during the  boot  process.   The
>        map  installer  and  configuration  files should go to /sbin and
>        /etc.
> ```

So, is good to make a backup for this folder from time to time.

See also: [What directories should I exclude when backing up?](https://serverfault.com/q/74696/181186)

---

And I think here is a good place to quote the chapter 1 from [The Tao Of Backup](http://www.taobackup.com/index.html):

> The novice asked the backup master which files he should backup.
>
> The master said: "Even as a shepherd watches over all the sheep in his
>   flock, and the lioness watches over all her cubs, so must you backup
>   every file in your care, no matter how lowly. For even the smallest
>   file can take days to recreate."
>
> The novice said: "I will save my working files, but not my system and
>   application files, as they can be always be reinstalled from their
>   distribution disks."
>
> The master made no reply.
>
> The next day, the novice's disk crashed. Three days later, the novice
>   was still reinstalling software.

Comment: "The Tao of Backup" is fantastic, thanks! About the boot folder: can you please elaborate: suppose my hard-drive crashes and I re-install Ubuntu on a new drive. This new installation already has a boot folder. So what should I do with my backuped boot folder?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi In case of a reinstall, there is not to much to do with the old `/boot`, but you might need to compare old boot config with new boot config. Just be sure not to restore `/boot` except manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare boot config"? Can you please point me to a reference so that I know how to compare my boot configs?